# How to automate Objective-C execution server-side

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ruby-on-rails

I'm an iPhone / Web Developer - and I've recently been trying out this site called [therubygame](http://www.therubygame.com/), which has simple puzzles for ruby developers to try out and submit various solutions for. It then automatically tests their code, gets a time for execution etc. and then ranks the solutions. - It also checks if the output is correct.

Now because the site itself is in rails, I would imagine it makes it a heck of a lot easier to run testing on ruby code dynamically.

Now I was wondering if it would be possible to do the same thing for Objective-C (with the foundation library). - Would it be possible to make a web application (either in PHP or rails), which can either tell the server to execute the code (in a sandboxed environment) or send it off to another computer for testing.

The two things it would have to do are get an execution time for the code, and check if the output is correct. - Also it must be able to execute against the foundation library (so the user can use classes such as `NSString` and `NSArray`.

Is this even possible in conjunction with something like PHP / Rails and a Linux Server - or  for this project to be viable would you have run Mac OS X Server?

Comment: Unless they have Objective-C compilers that will run on the php/rails server, you'd probably have to run a Mac OS X server with the XCode dev tools installed.  I'm not posting this as an answer because honestly I don't know.  I would think that you'd want to run the XCode dev tools so they are always current with the latest SDK (versus some 3rd party compiler that has to update all the time)